# Apppool recycle and Asp.net with threads?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis-6

I have made an asp.net page which executes a long sp.
lets say the the function that executes the sp is called `Func1`.

Ive met with that problem :

If i ran  `Func1`  in the same thread ( normal execution), the apppool won't recycle itself since he's seeing it as a busy/working.

But if I execute  `Func1` in another thread - so the apppool recycle's itself after the time that is set here :

[image]

My question is : **why** is that ?

is it true that if i run a command **synchronously** , so app is active and not eligible for apppool recycle ?
And if i create it in a new thread so it **does** eligible for apppool recycle ?

> why is that ? Does the thread is less important then the main thread ?

Comment: The thread will run inside the worker process as all threads run inside that

Comment: @ChrisS So why he is recycling when i run it in a thread , and when i run it in normal mode - it wont recycle itself ?

Comment: Do you want the job to run without having to keep the web page open? If so, try using the Cache object with the timeout option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET maintains a list of thread pool threads that it is using to service requests. It knows it can recycle the app domain when none of its threads are active.

If you create a thread or use a thread pool thread without the knowledge of ASP.NET, it will not detect that your thread is active and may recycle.

When it recycles, it unloads the `AppDomain` which causes a `ThreadAbortException` to be thrown on your thread.

---

The normal solution to your requirements is to have a windows service that is controlled by the web app. This is obviously in a separate process and so is not affected by the web app recycling. However, this is a non-trivial exercise.

The quick-and-dirty solution is to asynchronously start a web request from within your web app. The page that starts the operation can then return. The "hidden" page that was called can block until the SP has completed. As I said, this is a nasty-but-easy solution.

Comment: Hi thanks  , Is it possible that asp.net will tell IIS : **Listen my friend , the thread which John Created is my friend - please treat it as a one of the thread pool threads...and dont recycle if he is running... treat him as if it is a thread pool thread**

Comment: I have added two possible solutions to my answer.

Comment: Please confirm ( second solution ) :  I create A.aspx which has a button which when pressed it executes AsyncWebRequest  to Page called B.aspx which in his pageLoad he executes the sp . that way , The iis will treat the commands from B.aspx with thread pool - and it wont recycle... correct ? p.s Does it mean that A.aspx shouldnt be closed while B.aspx executes?

Comment: Yes - that's it. A.aspx can complete and B.aspx will execute the SP in the background.

Comment: Does it mean that A.aspx shouldnt be closed while B.aspx executes?

Comment: The user can close their browser window, if that's what you mean - it won't have any effect on B.aspx that was requested by the web app itself.

Comment: yesterday I though of another solution ( still messy)  : in A.aspx put a little 1px x 1px Iframe. and when the user press the button - in JS- put the src of the Iframe to B.aspx (which on his pageLoad it executes the Sp). what do you say about that idea ?