# Asp.Net MVC 5 - Long Running Task - How to ensure that worker thread won't be thrown away when IIS recycles the AppPool?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a data processing MVC application that works with uploaded file sizes ranging from 100MB to 2GB and contains a couple of long running operations. Users will upload the files and the data in those files will be processed and then finally some analysis on the data will be sent to related users/clients.

It will take least a couple of hours to process the data, so in order to make sure the user doesn't have to wait all the way, I've spun up a separate task to do this long running operation. This way, once the files are received by the server and stored on the disk, the user will get a response back with a ReferenceID and they can close the browser.

So far, it's been working well as intended but after reading up on issues with using Fire-and-Forget pattern in MVC and worker threads getting thrown away by IIS during recycling, I have concerns about this approach.

Is this approach still safe? If not, How can I ensure that the thread that is processing the data doesn't die until it finishes processing and sends the data to clients? (in a relatively simpler way)

The app runs on .NET 4.5, so don't think I will be able to use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` at the moment.

Does using Async/Await at controller help?

I've also thought of using a message queue on app server to store messages once the files are stored to disk and then making the DataProcessor a separate service/Process and then listen to the queue. If the queue is recoverable, then it will assure me that the messages will always get processed eventually even if the server crashes or the thread gets thrown away before finish processing the data. Is this a better approach?

My current setup is something like below

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ProcessFiles() 
{    
    HttpFileCollectionBase uploadedfiles = Request.Files;    

    var isValid = ValidateService.ValidateFiles(uploadedFiles);

    if(!isValid){
        return View("Error");
    }

    var referenceId = DataProcessor.ProcessData(uploadedFiles);

    return View(referenceId);    
}
```

**Business Logic**

```
public Class DataProcessor 
   {    
     public int ProcessFiles(HttpFileCollectionBase uploadedFiles) 
     {    
      var referenceId = GetUniqueReferenceIdForCurrentSession();

      var location = SaveIncomingFilesToDisk(referenceId, uploadedFiles);

      //ProcessData makes a DB call and takes a few hours to complete. 

      TaskFactory.StartNew(() => ProcessData(ReferenceId,location))
                 .ContinueWith((prevTask) => 
      {
         Log.Info("Completed Processing. Carrying on with other work");

         //Below method takes about 30 mins to an hour
         SendDataToRelatedClients(ReferenceId);  
      }    
      return referenceId;
     }

   }
```

**References**

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

[Apppool recycle and Asp.net with threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681851/apppool-recycle-and-asp-net-with-threads)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest firing up a non-ASP.NET controlled thread in ASP.NET ever, really. Instead, an out-of-process (ie. separate process) executable would make a lot more sense. You could use a scheduled task to watch your database for new "unprocessed data", and then process it as needed in the background completely away from your Application Pool.

Comment: Agreed with @RudiVisser... using a web application to run this kind of processes seems a bit overkilling to me. You should allow the upload trough your web server and have a job, scheduled task, windows service to be running on a separate task that takes care of data processing. Your web server just needs to be listening to the progress... but that could be done by adding a `progress row` somewhere in your data storage. That way you ensure not app pool or thread blocking on a webapp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My plan is to do the same for an optimal solution. However, as it is an existing app, it would first involve first resolving a lot of dependencies and then having the components (preferably windows services) work independently. I will make a decision on this soon.

Comment: I've gone with Hangfire, which Stephen mentions in his blog post, for a similar application. It's not optimal, but works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this approach still safe?

It was never safe.

> Does using Async/Await at controller help?

No.

> The app runs on .NET 4.5, so don't think I will be able to use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem at the moment.

I have an [AspNetBackgroundTasks library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) that essentially does the same thing as `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` (with minor differences). However...

> I've also thought of using a message queue on app server to store messages once the files are stored to disk and then making the DataProcessor a separate service/Process and then listen to the queue. If the queue is recoverable, then it will assure me that the messages will always get processed eventually even if the server crashes or the thread gets thrown away before finish processing the data. Is this a better approach?

Yes. This is the only reliable approach. It's what I call the "proper distributed architecture" in [my blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your post on this topic. I greatly enjoy reading your blog. I am leaning towards the option of using the queue in order to make the app more robust and distributed. I just need to think about the time required for removing all the dependencies in current version and creating independent components. I will have a look at your library as well to see if I can get a short-term fix.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe.  Create a service application on your server that handles these requests and publishes the result.  If you are hosted on Azure, take advantage of their [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-webjobs-resources) service.